# Eliminar directorios con PHP

Tags: php

Deseo eliminar una carpeta con `PHP`, intente con rmdir y me dice que el directorio no esta vacio. La carpeta contiene varias subcarpetas y archivos.

```
$resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM mapa WHERE ID_Mapa = '$borrar'");
                  while ($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultados)) {
                    $url= $consulta['URL'];
                  }
                  $dir = "../../maps/";
                  rmdir($dir . $url);
```

La variable de `$url` contiene el nombre de la carpeta.

Este es el mensaje que me arroja al correrlo:

> "Warning: rmdir(../../maps/2022_02_17-20_48_59_923135): Directory not
> empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\mapas\views\php\register.php on line 128"

Comment: Tienes un par de soluciones. 1) Recorrer primero la carpeta a borrar borrando sus archivos recursivamente (por si tiene más subcarpetas), o bien 2) Usar funciones que manden comandos al sistema, tipo shellexec() o similares, para enviarles un `rm -rf carpeta` donde **carpeta** sería la ruta completa al directorio que quieres eliminar. **Sobretodo asegúrate que pones bien la carpeta en este segundo caso o borrarás cosas que no debes**

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que  pasar una función recursiva . ya que puede que el directorio contenga carpetas y subcarpetas.

```html
 <?php
    function rmdir_recursive($dir) {
        if(!is_dir($dir)) return ;
        $files = scandir($dir);
        array_shift($files);    
        array_shift($files);  

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $file = $dir . '/' . $file;
            if (is_dir($file)) {
                rmdir_recursive($file);
                rmdir($file);
            }else unlink($file); 
            rmdir($dir);
        }
        rmdir($dir);
    }
    ?>
```

Para llamar a la función se hace de la siguiente manera

```html
 <?php
    $dir = "mi_sistema/carpeta_borrar";
    rmdir_recursive($dir);
 ?>
```

**Como funciona ?**

1. Verifica si la dirección enviada es un "directorio" y no un fichero.
2. Escanea el directorio en busca de archivos y carpetas, Lo convierte
   en un array
3. Elimina los dos primeros dos elementos del `Array`creado, siempre
   suelen ser ( ./  y ../)
4. Recorre el `Array` verificando si el elemento es una `carpeta` o un
   `fichero`, Si es una carpeta, La `función` se llama a si misma con
   la ruta de dicha carpeta (**Recursividad**), si es un `fichero` lo
   elimina.
5. Al finalizar borra la carpeta principal